# Ошибка при употреблении слова _включая_

Tags: уточнения

Он прибудет Москву, где он встретится с Лавровым, чтобы обсудить спектр двусторонних и региональных вопросов, включая Иран, Сирию и Украину.

Выходит, что обсудит Иран, Сирию и Украину, если понимать дословно. Можно ли так говорить? Или в публицистике возможны такие сокращения, вместо чтобы написать, скажем:

Он прибудет в Москву, где он встретится с Лавровым, чтобы обсудить спектр двусторонних и региональных вопросов, в том числе касающихся Ирана, Сирии и Украины.

Это имелось в виду?

Answer (score 1):

> Выходит, что обсудит Иран, Сирию и Украину, если понимать дословно.

Именно так. А как еще нужно понимать, если не дословно? И при чем тут "публицистика"? Это вопрос грамматики и семантики, не стилистика даже. Почему вдруг главы МИДа не могут обсудить Иран или Украину? (чисто с позиций грамматики, политику опускаем)?!

Тут, насколько понимаю, два момента. 
Первый в том, насколько уместно использовать "включая" в значении "в том числе". Кому-то может показаться странным, но если вспомнить, что включая - не только деепричастие, но и предлог, сомнения должны исчезнуть.

И второе, насколько Иран и Сирия могут быть "вопросом". Т.е. могут ли главы МИД (и вообще кто-либо) обсуждать сами страны, а не **ситуацию** в них. Тут да, есть о чем подумать. В строгом официальном тексте я бы предпочел скорее *"обсудят... [вопросы]..., включая **ситуацию** в Иране, Сирии, Украине"*. Но в тексте заметки... Не вижу проблем и тут.

Answer (score 1):

Это издержки перевода.

"Госсекретарь США Джон Керри 11 мая отправится в Сочи, 12 мая он встретится с президентом РФ Путиным, министром иностранных дел Лавровым и другими российскими официальными лицами, чтобы обсудить полный спектр двусторонних и региональных вопросов, включая Иран, Сирию и Украину", - отмечается в официальном сообщении Госдепа. Должно бы быть "**...включая вопросы Ирана,Сирии и Украины"**.Видимо, так убрали повтор.

Есть другой перевод: «Джон Керри намерен обсудить широкий спектр вопросов двусторонней и региональной проблематики, включая Иран, Сирию и Украину... », — отмечается в сообщении посольства США в Москве. Здесь вроде бы чуть лучше.

А вообще, в журналистике, действительно, такие ляпы часты, вероятно, газетчики скоро свой синтаксис выработают - основанный на **метонимии**, как в этом случае.

Вот такое оформление цитаты  уже вполне законно: Информацию о визите Керри в Сочи также подтвердили в Государственном департаменте США, передает "Укринформ". И не прямая речь, и не косвенная с помощью вводного сочетания (должно бы быть "**КАК передаёт...**"), а совмещение косвенной и несобственно прямой речи. Видимо, новый стиль создаётся.

Comment: а есть оригинальный текст, где следует что это перевод - и там именно два раза вопросы?

Comment: ... discuss a full range of bilateral and regional issues, including Iran, Syria, and Ukraine.

Comment: Там о диапазоне "региональных проблем", но проблемы тоже со странами отождествлены; нашлась только цитата и не исключено, что это не письменный документ, а запись с телефонного пресс-брифинга Госдепа - это практикуется.

Answer (score 0):

...вопросов, включая Иранский, Сирийский, Украинский. Ответ: не сокращения такие, а неуважение.